# am startservice has no network permission

Tags: android, service

I wrote a service, which is contained in an APK. In this APK, I have not any activity at all. The definition is as following:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service android:name="com.blackforest.service.KeyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.blackforest.service.KeyService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

I compiled it and install the APK via pm install in a real Android phone, and I try to start this service via this command:

```
am startservice --user 0 -n com.blackforest.service/.KeyService
```

This service can be booted correctly. But it seems that this service don't have the network permission. as it send the request, I got the following errors:

```
02-23 16:22:29.685 22689-22714/com.blackforest.service W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "bf.xxxx.com": No address associated with hostname
02-23 16:22:29.686 22689-22714/com.blackforest.service W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
02-23 16:22:29.686 22689-22714/com.blackforest.service W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-23 16:22:29.686 22689-22714/com.blackforest.service W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-23 16:22:29.686 22689-22714/com.blackforest.service W/System.err:     at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
```

I am definitely sure the domain bf.xxxx.com is reachable via this mobile phone.

And I made a little change, adding a blank activity in this APK, and reinstall it. First I launched the activity in the screen, and then started the service via am startservice. At this time, the service works very well.

My question is, why the service don't have network permission if there is only the service in the APK booting through the am command?

Explanation is ugly expected! Much thanks.

The entire manifest.xml is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service android:name="com.blackforest.service.KeyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"

        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.blackforest.service.KeyService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

PS: Android in this mobile is 4.4.4

Comment: Could you put the entire manifest ? Just to see the permission you add

Comment: @Timo just added, thanks

Comment: And which version of android ?

Comment: android version is 4.4.4

Comment: Could you put the part of the service which call this URL ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the version of Android > 6 you have to request permission : [Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

EDIT :

I'm not sure but the permission of your service depend of the permission of the activity which start the service so you need to specify in your manifest when you define your service the permission it need take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) section : android:permission

Comment: My android version in this mobile is 4.4.4